# Stop lines in GDocs chart overlapping/obscuring other lines

Tags: google-sheets

How can I stop lines in GDocs chart overlapping/obscuring other lines? See for example the green line in the graph below, which starts up high, butthen goes behind other lines such as the yellow one.

[image: graph]

Comment: Can you share that spreadsheet with us, so we can have a look?

Comment: Yes, part of the green series is the same as part of the yellow series. I'm not so keen on what you'd suggest - ideally I could make the lines dashed and interleaving.

Answer (score 1):

I agree dashed would appear best in the circumstances but I'm afraid that does not *seem* to be an option. BTW I've only just seen your latest comment (no 'ping' to it).

With examples as below the top left chart shows the red line heavily obscuring the blue over the range where the example data is identical for both series - not good. The chart below that is with a small offset to the red series. I think a viable solution for the odd chart or two but I agree tedious for many charts (if they insist on overlapping!) as I added the offset manually.

So I offer an alternative which is on the right - increase the thickness of the blue line, reduce that of the red and add markers to it.

[image: WA35937 example]